# Как установить разные версии Django на ПК с Windows 7

Tags: windows, установка, django

Чтобы потом среди них не путаться. Вопрос возможно ламерский, но хочу заранее подготовиться, если придется одновременно работать с разными версиями фреймворка

Comment: Традиционный подход - использование изолированных окружений python. Делается это с помощью утилиты virtualenv. Под win xp она прекрасно работает, вероятно под win 7 тоже должна.

Comment: под Win 7 использую, вот еще ссылочка на виндовый wrapper https://github.com/davidmarble/virtualenvwrapper-win

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используй virtualenv, вот пример настройки: [Знакомимся с virtualenv](http://python-lab.blogspot.com/2012/07/virtualenv.html)

Comment: спасибо! Кажется, я нашел ответ на свой вопрос